# Backup files before replace

Tags: inno-setup

I am attempting to create an installer for a MOD but have run into the issue of when it is uninstalled it will revert back to its former state.

I have figured out how to backup the entire folder but I would like to back up **only files and folders of the files that will be overwritten**.

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\_backup"

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\User\Mod\bin"; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion createallsubdirs recursesubdirs
Source: "{app}\*"; DestDir: "{app}\_backup"; Flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

How would this be done?

Comment: You could split install of source files and add `BeforeInstall` event code that would check if file exists and then back it up.

Comment: Is there a way to determine the current file that is being extracted or get a list of files to be extracted, then I would be able to loop though the list and backup the files as you said?

Comment: Figured out you can use `CurrentFileName` to get the file currently being processed which is what i needed to write the function, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, that might work. From `BeforeInstall` function you can get the `CurrentFileName` value.